# Is it possible to make HTML5 3D cube run with PhoneGap?

Tags: html, css, cordova, css-animations

I found a few great examples on building 3D Cubes with HTML5 and CSS, however non of them seem to work when I deploy them to my phonegap application.

http://www.paulrhayes.com/2010-09/3d-css-cube-ii-touch-gestures-click-and-drag/
http://desandro.github.io/3dtransforms/docs/cube.html

I guess I misunderstood something or doing it wrong, any suggestions ?

Comment: what version of android device have you tested it? or on what device did you test it?

Comment: 2.3 Galaxy S2, do you think it would work with a higher version ?

Comment: Im sure that 2.3 does not support 3d animations and other css3, try to test it on a higher version of android

Comment: @blender_noob Thanks I will try out now! if it worked make your comment an answer :)

Comment: your welcome! if you wanted to test or check if html5 features is supported on a device's browser check it here: 
Android 2.3 -
http://html5test.com/compare/browser/android23.html
Other:
http://html5test.com/results/gaming.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few years late to answer this one, by now the answer is still kind Yes, and here are the potential approaches:

- [WebGL tutorial](http://www.agilityfeat.com/blog/2015/08/using-webgl-in-ios-without-phonegap-or-ionic)
- [WebGL 2nd example](http://html5gamedevelopment.com/2012-01-webglgap-webgl-in-phonegap/)
- [Threejs](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/703761/Discovering-Three-js-with-Android-and-Intel-XDK) or [Tridiv](http://tridiv.com/)
- [Wikitude AR library](http://docs.phonegap.com/tutorials/develop/wikitude/)
- [ThreeJS and VR within browser](https://www.sitepoint.com/bringing-vr-to-web-google-cardboard-three-js/)

For the ThreeJS on Android, the Chrome App can be used to make this happen.